# Usage of "give it a read"

Tags: phrases, expressions

Is the usage of the phrase "give it a read" correct? For instance, "Hey, I have attached my essay. Do give it a read and let me know what you think".

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: It's fine to use in informal situations. You would say "look over it" or "read through it" in more formal contexts.

Comment: ok thanks!.. in a similar vein, is "give it a listen" fine too?

Comment: Note that "give it a read" is informal.  Otherwise there's nothing wrong with the way you've used it.

Comment: @srinivas.naik Only if you're reading the essay aloud or playing a piece of music (i.e., sound is involved)

Comment: Note the approving use of "It's a good read."

Comment: @Dog Lover--I would suggest that it might be better to say "look it over" than "look over it," which sounds like a non-native error (unless you mean to focus your eyes above some object).

Answer (score -1):

You can also say, " You may want to go through it. Please let me know what are your thoughts about it. "